# Angular DOM Reload when using dom-to-image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, caching

I'm using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) in my program to change divs into image, My problem is that the divs are calculated from parameters so I need to convert them multiple time.

So I'm using this script:

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';

convert() {
    const list = (<HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName('indicator-wrapper'));
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        domtoimage.toPng(list[i]).then(function (dataUrl) {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = dataUrl;
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
            });
    }
}
```

[image: console]

For each call it download all my resources again:

> 840 times | 18:59:49.418 | XHR finished loading: GET "".
>
> 96 times  | 18:59:50.305 | XHR finished loading: GET "?".

why does this happen?

Comment: Find an interesting topic, maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131823/angular5-xhr-finished-loading-get-url-keeps-running

Comment: @shaochuancs thanks for the links but I think I found the issue "find all the @ font-face declarations that might represent web fonts"  download all the fonts of my web apps even if none are needed and so for each image. The lib need some reworks I guess.